# Firefox addon - how to use XMLHttpRequest in Chromeworker?

Tags: ajax, xmlhttprequest, firefox-addon

I am using ChromeWorker to download some data from a API.
I am trying to import XHR in **myWorker.js**.

`importScripts("resource://gre/modules/workers/require.js");
 var { XMLHttpRequest } = require("sdk/net/xhr");`

I am getting the following error while running **cfx run**

```
Error: TypeError: The argument to require() must be a string uri, got sdk/net/xhr
```

I am using this demo https://github.com/Noitidart/ChromeWorker
How do I import and use XMLHttpRequest in **myWorker.js** ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I modded my non-worker XHR function to work in ChromeWorker, but its not perfect as I don't know how to set loadFlags in the ChromeWorker version as in the ChromeWorker version doesnt have `.channels`, weird.

https://gist.github.com/Noitidart/ec1e6b9a593ec7e3efed

My function there uses a promise scheme but you can do it without that like this:

```
var aOptions = {
responseType: 'text'
}
var aStr = 'http://www.bing.com/';
let xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
let evf = f => ['load', 'error', 'abort'].forEach(f);
    if (aOptions.aPostData) {
        xhr.open('POST', aStr, true);
        //xhr.channel.loadFlags |= aOptions.aLoadFlags; // i dont know how to do this from ChromeWorker yet
        xhr.responseType = aOptions.aResponseType;
        xhr.send(aOptions.aPostData);       
    } else {
        xhr.open('GET', aStr, true);
        //xhr.channel.loadFlags |= aOptions.aLoadFlags; // i dont know how to do this from ChromeWorker yet
        xhr.responseType = aOptions.aResponseType;
        xhr.send(null);
    }
```

Jump on moz js-ctypes irc channel for more help :)
irc://moznet/jsctypes

Comment: Thanks for your answer. When I use XMLHttpRequest, it says undefined. `let xhr = new XMLHttpRequest(); //Cc["@mozilla.org/xmlextras/xmlhttprequest;1"].createInstance(Ci.nsIXMLHttpRequest);` How do I import Cc here?

Comment: @ValarpiraichandranA no need for Cc I commented that part out as I was trying to show that `new XMLHttpRequest()` is replacement for `Cc....`

Comment: I tried directly using XMLHttpRequest without importing it. Working fine. Thankyou very much.

Comment: the myWorker.js link is dead

Comment: Ah here is my xhr function for workers - https://gist.github.com/Noitidart/ec1e6b9a593ec7e3efed